# Jqm submit button on a fixed footer

Tags: jquery-mobile, footer, css-position

I have a form that I would like to put the submit button on the fixed footer bar. Problem is that if I put the footer inside the form its not fixed at the bottom. If I move the footer outside the form then the submit button will not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: place the submit button outside footer then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wire up the click event of your footer button to submit your form.

```
<a data-role="button" onclick="$('#yourForm').submit();">Save</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you get the button on the footer like @andleer says you may want to hide your buttons in the form.

Due to the fact that jqm 'enhances' your code you can't do a simple jQuery `hide()`.  I thought I would provide a way to do it here as it took me a bit to get it right.

```
$('#[THE PAGE THAT YOUR FORM IS ON]').on( "pagebeforeshow", function(e) {
    if(e.handled !== true) {
        $('#submit-btn').parent().hide();
        $('#cancel-btn').parent().hide();
        e.handled = true;
    }
});
```

As a side note the `e.handled` is here to keep the code from being run multiple times based on how jqm loads scripts and pages.